# Как передать параметр из адресной строки в форму и откуда его взять?

Tags: php, параметры

Есть лендинг.

Я хочу чтобы было известно из какой ПС пришел посетитель и по какому запросу?
Я так понял это записывается в адресную строку.
И потом эти данные должны отправляться в форму, которую он заполняет на сайте, скрытыми полями.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Воспользуйтесь переменной `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` но не факт что она у вас будет заполнена для Яндекса ибо они сейчас прячут эту информацию. Саму страницу вы получите а вот поискового слова там не будет. Для других поисковиков должно работать.